# Draw areas from KML content

Tags: angular, leaflet, kml

In my Angular2 project, I use leafletJS with kml plugin to draw areas.

like this

```
var track = new L.KML("KML_Samples.kml", {async: true});
track.on("loaded", function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
});
map.addLayer(track);
```

Now, the API returns directly the KML content

My question is that there is a way that the KML plugin consumes KML content instead of a url, or is it possible to create a virtual file and pass its url

Answer (score 0):

I get there by creating a data link, using

```
var src = 'data:application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,'+ btoa(KmlBody);

let kmlLayer = new L.KML(src, {async: true});

track.on("loaded", function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
});

map.addLayer(kmlLayer);
```